# Windows 10 Update to 1903 Error: 0x8007042B - 0x2000D

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

The update starts on the windows 10 machine but after the restart everything is rolled back.

My setuperr.txt:

```
2019-07-16 16:38:55, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #10# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = 974 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup'), vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-07-16 16:38:55, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #9# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:31]'\Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\Setup\', vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
﻿2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1253): Result = 0xC1800104[gle=0x00000002]
2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::CheckUserInterruptEx(3060): Result = 0x800704D3
2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::CheckUserInterrupt(3112): Result = 0x800704D3
2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(794): Result = 0x800705BB
2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(392): Result = 0x800705BB
2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(284): Result = 0x800705BB
2019-07-16 16:38:58, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(412): Result = 0x800705BB
2019-07-16 16:39:18, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #38# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = 570 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup'), vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-07-16 16:39:18, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #37# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:31]'\Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\Setup\', vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-07-16 16:39:21, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #70# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = 570 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts'), vn = [l:21 ml:22]'Arial Nova (TrueType)', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-07-16 16:39:21, Error                 CSI    00000004 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #69# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:69]'\Registry\Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts\', vn = [l:21 ml:22]'Arial Nova (TrueType)', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-07-16 16:39:55, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to set WU internal configuration property for targeted scans. hr = 0x80070057
2019-07-16 16:40:52, Error                 CONX   0xd0000034 Failed to add user mode driver [%SystemRoot%\system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\uicciso.dll]

2019-07-16 16:44:14, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2019-07-16 16:45:10, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #519832# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216, status = '(null)', value = { type: 40972, bytes ( 12 ): 640065002d00440045000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-07-16 16:45:57, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2019-07-16 16:48:11, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2019-07-16 16:48:11, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
```

I tried already:

- Chkdsk c: /F
- Dism
- SFC /scannow
- In-place upgrade
- reset Windows Update

Comment: Do you have any external disks connect to your system?  How are you performing the update thorugh what mechanism?  There is a known issue with 1903 with external disk which has been reported to also effect secondary internal drives.

Comment: Are you running the update from Windows Settings? If so, download the ISO and do an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @Ramhound External disks only network shares from a server. No second internal drive. Does your mentioned bug also include network shares? First i tried through regular Windows Update, then via the Official Windows Update Tool from the Microsoft homepage, then via an in-place Upgrade from an ISO and finally via the installation media creation tool.

Comment: @harrymc as mentioned in the original problem I already tried both methods you mentioned

Comment: Then the problem might be corruption or hardware. Check Event Viewer for error messages. I hope you have not run a registry cleaner that destroyed Windows, but if you did, try to rollback to a System Restore point from before that.

Comment: @harrymc No registry cleaner used. Error log is provided in the original question.

Comment: I asked because it seems that you are missing important parts of the registry. If not a cleaner, then perhaps the computer is infected.

Comment: I don't think infection is a real threat here. What important parts of the registry do you see missing?

Comment: If you have 3rd party AV, Malware prevention, or firewall software, fully disable all of it.  Issue the following within an admin prompt and in the order listed: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`, `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, Reboot PC, `sfc /scannow`, Reboot PC, retry update.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly same errors repeatedly, until I updated all Dell drivers separately, then used the ISO in-place upgrade and selected to skip updates when installing. Hope it helps.

Comment: Windows 10 will update all drivers, except CPU related drivers _(Chipset, IMEI, etc.)_, with their WHQL versions via Windows Update, however I'm not sure if Windows Update is able to pull customized drivers from OEMs (such as integrated graphics drivers).